# Git Extensions and newer version of Git compatibility?

Tags: git

Are there any known issues using Git Extensions with newer version of Git than the one that it comes with?

I am currently using latest Git Extensions v2.47.3 (out of the box comes with Git 1.8.3) with Git 1.9.2 and have not run issues. However I am about to recommend the same combination at my work for others to use and was wondering whether there are issues that are not obvious when using Git Extensions with later versions of Git.

The main reason I want to use later version of Git is to be able to do shallow submodule clones which is not available in Git 1.8.3.

Comment: Being able to do something extra is not a problem. Changing how existing functionality works would. Git maintainers are generally quite careful not to and make any changed behaviour opt-in on configuration option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any known issues using Git Extensions with newer version of Git than the one that it comes with?

Not many. I have found one ([issue 2296](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2296)) regarding ssh, but beside that, nothinig incompatible with existing git features.

Submodules are improving ([issue 2161](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2161)) in [term of presentation](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/submodules.html), but the underlying msysgit features are not incompatible with what GFE is expecting.